# Export dataFrame to excel without lose the format python

Tags: python, dataframe

When the data is into dataFrame, everything shows ok. DataFrame values:

[image]

But after I export it to Excel, the values are not respecting their format. Excel values:

[image]

The code I'm using to export is this one:

```
 with pd.ExcelWriter('test_3_tabs.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', date_format='dd/mm/yyyy', datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as writer:
        diferencaValores3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Diferença Peso e qtd', index=False)
        diferencaEmpresa.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Existe a mais na Empresa', index=False) 
        diferencaErp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Existe a mais no ERP', index=False)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why EAN value is not showing in Excel? How can I export to Excel without losing the data format?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stackoverflow! IMO you could enhance your post by showing the screenshots inline (instead of using a external link).

Answer (score 0):

you can set-up different excel parameters and format specific columns from different sheets. For example, we can force the column B (ean) to be an integer :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('test_3_tabs.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', date_format='dd/mm/yyyy', datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Diferença Peso e qtd', index=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Existe a mais na Empresa', index=False) 
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Existe a mais no ERP', index=False)
    
    # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Diferença Peso e qtd']
    worksheet2 = writer.sheets['Existe a mais na Empresa']
    worksheet3 = writer.sheets['Existe a mais no ERP']
    
    # Add some cell formats.
    format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#'})

    # Set the column width and format.
    worksheet1.set_column('B:B', 20, format1)
    worksheet2.set_column('B:B', 20, format1)
    worksheet3.set_column('B:B', 20, format1)
```